# How can I skip empty values when iterating?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, iteration

[Github Link](https://github.com/rygrant520/totalwine-product-details-scraper.git)

I keep getting partly through running this code before `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` gets thrown. However, I make it through many lines that write into my csv file before the error is thrown. I believe that it is due to one of the fieldnames not being present when iterating.  Does anyone know what I can add to this to skip these fields and move on the the next item?

```
with open("urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('data.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=["product_name","product_image","product_desc","product_company","product_country","product_type","product_abv","product_taste"],quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data:
            for r in data['product']:
                writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: What's the error? [Related](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Maybe `if data and 'product' in data:`?

Comment: @TimRoberts that didn't seem to work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the line it's complaining about?  You're iterating in two places here, so either your "urllist.read() is returning None or data['product'] is None sometimes.

Comment: @EddieParker I just added a line to Github, hopefully you can tell what is going on.  I feel like i've tried everything

Comment: Which line, EXACTLY, gets the error?  Perhaps you should show the whole traceback.

Comment: https://github.com/rygrant520/totalwine-product-details-scraper.git

Comment: Hey Ryan: that link is a 404.  I bet it's a private repository.  Moreover, you're sending the link to an entire repository, when all we really need is the full error message.  I'd recommend you just copy the whole error output to your error above.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try defaulting the product key?

```
if data:
    for r in data.get('product', []):
        # action
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work either

Comment: If that doesn't help I imagine the error is stemming from your " for url in urllist.read().splitlines():" line as that's the only other place you're iterating.  Do you have a traceback you can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('data.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=["product_name","product_image","product_desc","product_company","product_country","product_type","product_abv","product_taste"],quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        if not url:
            continue
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data and data['product']:
            for r in data['product']:
                writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

***Attempting to improve my contributions:***

> csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)

If your suspicions are correct and a missing field name is the cause, it should be as easy as setting a default value for any missing field names via the `csv.DictWriter(restval='something')` parameter.

Should the issue prove *not* to be the field name, you could always try `csv.DictReader(extrasaction='ignore')` though this has the potential of skipping over data that you may need written to the file ... depending on where - in that data - your issue lies.

Comment: i kept getting an error saying that outfile was not defined when I did this.